# Multiple royalslider index indicator on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have multiple fullscreen royalsliders in main page. I want to get the slide index for each slider.
Is it possible to do this in one code by using for loop or something else?
html is;

```
<div id="page">
        <div id="ref1" class="screen">
            <div class="royalSlider rsDefaultInv">
                <img src="images/projects/1.jpg" />
                <img src="images/projects/1.jpg" />
            </div> 
            <div class="slider-detail">
                <div class="box hdd">
                    <div class="detail-left">Project 1 <span>/BRANDING</span></div>
                    <div class="detail-right">
                        <a class="detail-btn fr" href="javascript:void(0)" rel="nofollow"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bg"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="project-detail">
                <p class="big-text">Project 1 info</p>
                <a class="link" href="#" title="">WEBSITE</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="ref2" class="screen">
            <div class="royalSlider rsDefaultInv">
                <img src="images/projects/2.jpg" />
                <img src="images/projects/2.jpg" />
            </div> 
            <div class="slider-detail">
                <div class="box hdd">
                    <div class="detail-left">Project 2 <span>/BRANDING</span></div>
                    <div class="detail-right">
                        <a class="detail-btn fr" href="javascript:void(0)" rel="nofollow"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bg"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="project-detail">
                <p class="big-text">Project 2 info</p>
                <a class="link" href="#" title="">WEBSITE</a>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

and here is js;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
```

var rsi = $('#ref1 .royalSlider, #ref2 .royalSlider').royalSlider({
    autoHeight: false,
    arrowsNav: true,
    globalCaption:false,
    arrowsNavAutoHide: false,
    fadeinLoadedSlide: false,
    controlNavigationSpacing: 30,
    controlNavigation: 'null',
    imageScaleMode: 'fill',
    imageAlignCenter: false,
    addActiveClass:true,
    loop: true,
    loopRewind: true,
    numImagesToPreload: 4,
    keyboardNavEnabled: true,
    autoScaleSlider: false,
    autoScaleSliderWidth: 640,
    autoScaleSliderHeight: 360,
    imgWidth: 1920,
    imgHeight: 1080

}).data('royalSlider');

```
$('.screen').each(function() {
    var slider = $(this).children();
    for (var i = 1; i < $(slider).length; i++) {
        var ref = '#ref'+i
        var sliderInstance = $(ref) + ' ' + slider.data('royalSlider');
    }       

    if (sliderInstance) {           
        var slideCounter = $('<div class="sliderCount"></div>').appendTo($(ref + ' ' + '.slider-detail .box .detail-right'))
        var updCount = function() {
            slideCounter.html( (sliderInstance.currSlideId+1) + ' / ' + sliderInstance.numSlides );
        }
        sliderInstance.ev.on('rsAfterSlideChange', updCount);
        updCount();
    }

});
```

});

Problem solved! The code should be like this;

```
$('.royalSlider').each(function() {
    var slider = $(this);
    var sliderInstance = slider.data('royalSlider');

    if(sliderInstance) {
        var slideCounter = $('<div class="rsSlideCount"></div>').appendTo( slider.next().find('.detail-right') );

        var updCount = function () {
            slideCounter.html( (sliderInstance.currSlideId+1) + ' of ' + sliderInstance.numSlides );
        }
        sliderInstance.ev.on('rsAfterSlideChange', updCount);
        updCount();
    }

});
```

Comment: Isn't `currSlideId` giving you the index?

Comment: Your `for` loop is odd, it's looping though all the children but not all of them are sliders.

Comment: Yes i know. Because project details are hidden. They are opening by clicking on the detail button. So I left slider-detail div out of the slider

Comment: By the end of one for loop, you are trying to access `#ref3`, which does not exist.

Comment: problem is solved! i will edit the post